# Access denied moving folders from Dropbox to Desktop

Tags: windows-8.1, dropbox

Simply put, I'm trying to move two folders from my Dropbox folder to my desktop.

Sometimes it works, sometimes it says, "Access is denied".

This is the code for the batch:

```
@echo off
:start
move "C:\Users\x\Dropbox\MC_Servers\ec2\Server\backups" "C:\Users\x\Desktop\Server Backups\"
move "C:\Users\x\Dropbox\MC_Servers\ec2\Server\logs" "C:\Users\x\Desktop\Server Backups\"
timeout /t 7200
goto start
```

I have tried running as admin, changing UAC to th lowest setting, and changing folder permissions.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do get rid of the restriction and stop it from denying access.

Answer (score 1):

Run your batch using RoboCopy. It will try more often and the access denied, if it is caused by Dropbox using the file, will eventually release it. Even with RoboCopy, Dropbox will sometimes hold files in use even after not reading it, so your mileage may vary. You may need to use a tool such as [handle](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to close the handle a process is using to keep the file open.

Comment: I would use robocopy, but I'm moving it in order to keep space free on my Dropbox.

Comment: RoboCopy has a /move flag so it will moves files. It works just like move but has more options such as a default retry... which is what you want.

Comment: Useful, but not the answer. Upvoted, though.

Comment: I think it addresses your issue with Access is Denied. There is a reason for being denied access and robocopy will retry until Dropbox releases the file for other software to use. Why do you feel it does not answer your question?

Comment: Because since the dropbox folder will basically be constantly used, it may not always work.

Comment: It will work more times then trying to move it once. You could also exit out of Dropbox before you run the script. Our as a command line use process.exe from beyond logic to kill the Dropbox.exe process via command line.